# Why different behavior for CTRL + SHIFT + ARROW_DOWN in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

CTRL + SHIFT + ARROW_DOWN suppose to select the entire column to the end from where current sell downward but this behaviour is different for different columns in the same excel file.

For some columns, it works and select the entire data in the column to end.

There are certain columns where it only selects the next cell under only even though there is continous data.

There are other columns where it selects a range of cells but not all the way to the end of the file.

Why is different and what should I do if I need to select the column to the end of the file?

If this matters, CTRL + SPACE also has varied behavour, for some columns, it selects that column, for other columns, it selects a bunch of columns (instead of the single column).

Comment: They will stop at the first empty cell.  If the data has blanks in it then that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the end question, how do you select from some cell to the absolute end of the used cells in its column, just press `Ctrl-Shift-END` to select from it to the absolute end of your used cells, probably seeing more than one column selected, the continue to hold `Ctrl-Shift` while using either the left or right arrow key, as needed to move that direction until only a single column is highlighted.

Then, if you want, you can simply use that. Or at this point you can continue to hold `Ctrl-Shift` while pressing the UP arrow to move up to the last used cell in that column. Note though, that if you are choosing this range in aid of a function that uses another range and they have to be the same size or Excel will return an error, you need to use the `Ctrl-Shift-(UP) Arrow` to select exactly the matching length range.

As to the rest of the material in the question, I do NOT experience what you experience. I have release 2105, so current, but do not believe there are any changes to this set of commands' behaviors. They're too basic.

I would point out though, that when Excel is selecting a range and it encounters merged cells, it will extend the highlighting to include all columns that the merged cells are in. So trying to highlight A1:A10 if cells A3:C3 are merged will include all three columns even using these shortcut key combos. You'd end up with the range A1:C10 selected.

If writing a formula, no problem. Just let that range appear, then edit it. If selecting for something like `Find and Replace` and not wanting to affect, say, column B, you are out of luck. You'd have to do it in pieces working around the merged cells (so A1:A2, then A4:A10 in this example), or unmerge any merged cells, do the `F&R`, then re-merge the merged combos.

Thanks though. When playing around with the key combos, I noticed something I'd never noticed before:  `Ctrl-Shift-Space` selects anything contiguous enough that Excel evaluates it as a related range. So selected cell is A4, `Ctrl-Shift-Space` selects A1:B10. I might find that useful sometime, seems I should anyway.